# Transpose row factor to column

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

I have a data frame like this in R:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B"), 
                 var2 = c(-1,0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4,-1,-1),
                 var3 = c("pp","mm","mm","mm","mm","mm","oo","rr"),
                 var4 = c(2,1,4,3,6,4,7,2))
```

And the expected result should be like this:

```
 df2 <- data.frame(var1 =   c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B"),
    var2 = c(-1,0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4,-1),
    pp = c(2,NA, NA,NA, NA,NA, NA) , 
    mm = c(NA,1,4,3,6,4,NA ) , 
    oo = c(NA,NA, NA,NA, NA,NA, 7) , 
    rr = c(NA,NA, NA,NA, NA,NA, 2))
```

Where the levels within the column `var2` have moved to different columns but keeping the same information in the `var1`, and `var2`. The `var2` should show a unique identifier according to the levels of `var1`

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_wider(df, id_cols = c("var1", "var2"), names_from = "var3", values_from = "var4")` or `reshape2::dcast(var1 + var2 ~ var3, data = df, value.var = "var4")`

Comment: If the comment-code doesn't work and the dupe-links don't give you enough information, please @-ping me and we can work through the concerns. Good luck!